# Function return before executing entire code

Tags: c

I am trying to "test" my hardware by running a script

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    static unsigned int end_number = 100000;

    unsigned int no_primes = 0;
    unsigned int primes[end_number];
    unsigned int index = 0;

    uint8_t found_prime = 0;

    double start = (double)clock();

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < end_number; i++)
    {
        found_prime = 1;

        for (unsigned int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                found_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found_prime == 1)
        {
            primes[index] = i;
            index++;
            no_primes++;
        }
    }

    double end = (double)clock();

    double compute_time = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Find all primes up to: %u\n", end_number);
    printf("Time elapsed: %f seconds\n", compute_time);
    printf("Number of primes found: %u\n", no_primes);
    return 0;
}
```

It finds all the prime numbers between 1 and `end_number`. For now, it works.
But when I try to run it as a function, it skips the for loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double bench(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int end_number = n;

    unsigned int no_primes = 0;
    unsigned int primes[end_number];
    unsigned int index = 0;

    uint8_t found_prime = 0;

    double start = (double)clock();

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < end_number; i++)
    {
        found_prime = 1;

        for (unsigned int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                found_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found_prime == 1)
        {
            primes[index] = i;
            index++;
            no_primes++;
        }
    }

    double end = (double)clock();

    double compute_time = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    return compute_time;
}

int main()
{
    double compute_time = bench(100000);
    printf("Time elapsed: %f seconds\n", compute_time);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for (unsigned int j = 2; j < i; j++)  this condition is false ,  j=2 > i=1

Comment: `%Lf` should be `%f`.

Comment: The code you posted executes `bench`, which I assume is what you mean it executes when "run it as a function". This function executes the outer `for` loop precisely 99,999 times. I don't understand why you think it "skips" it. And the inner loop's body executes 455,189,149 times.

Comment: *"it skips the for loops"* How do you determine that?

Comment: @nissimabehcera I tried for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++). Sadly doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffHolt It execute way faster than the original code and if you increase n, compute_time doesn't change.

Comment: need to include <stdint.h> if using uint8_t; but with that change this runs on onlinegdb.com

Comment: @thelizardking34 including <stdint.h> or changing uint8_t to int doesn't change the output

Comment: Neither the first or the second code ever reads from `primes` so the compiler might be optimizing it out.

Comment: @dbush I think this is what happened, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but adding  `printf("%u\n", no_primes);` before returning solved it.